# matplotlib - UserWarning: Legend does not support handles for Annotation instances

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], label='line1')
ax.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], label='line2')
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(0.4,1.0),
            xytext=(0.4,0.0),
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'->' },
            label='distance')
ax.legend()
```

It's generating the result as I expect but it's also returning a warning:

[image]

```
UserWarning: Legend does not support handles for Annotation instances.
See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler
  ax.legend()
```

Using `matplotlib` v3.7.1. How can tell `matplotlib` to just *ignore* the annotation for the legend?